Unable to integrate asyncio and scrapy
I have this spider:
import logging

from scrapy import Spider, Request, settings

from dummy  import settings
from dummy.items import DummyItem

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class DummySpider(Spider):
    name = 'DummySpider'

    def start_requests(self) -> Request:
        LOGGER.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! run start_requests")
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        LOGGER.info(f'reactor_class: {reactor.__class__}')
        LOGGER.info(f'scrapy_twisted_reactor: {settings.TWISTED_REACTOR}')

        yield Request('https://google.com', dont_filter=True)

    async def parse(self, _, **kwargs) -> DummyItem:
        LOGGER.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! run parse")
        item = DummyItem()
        item['id'] = 42
        yield item

If I run it with scrapy:
2024-12-03 13:54:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2024-12-03 13:54:19 [dummy.spiders.dummy] INFO: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! run start_requests
2024-12-03 13:54:19 [dummy.spiders.dummy] INFO: reactor_class: <class 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'>
2024-12-03 13:54:19 [dummy.spiders.dummy] INFO: scrapy_twisted_reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2024-12-03 13:54:19 [dummy.spiders.dummy] INFO: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! run parse
2024-12-03 13:54:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.google.com/>
{'id': 42}
2024-12-03 13:54:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

Now, if I try to use CrawlerRunner instead, it just hangs:
from scrapy.utils.reactor import install_reactor
install_reactor('twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor')
import asyncio
import logging

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.defer import deferred_to_future
from twisted.internet import reactor

from dummy.spiders.dummy import DummySpider

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class TaskError(Exception):
    pass


async def run_scraper() -> None:
    crawler_runner = CrawlerRunner()
    deferred = crawler_runner.crawl(DummySpider)
    print(deferred)
    future = deferred_to_future(deferred)
    print(future)
    print(reactor.__class__)
    await deferred_to_future(deferred)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run_scraper())

<Deferred at 0x71cf0c6c3e90>
<Future pending cb=[Deferred.asFuture.<locals>.checkCancel() at .venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:1214]>
<class 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'>



The way to start the reactor is always:
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.run()

Or some abstraction on top of this (like twisted.internet.task.react).  asyncio is the lower level API.  If you start it directly, you bypass all of Twisted's own initialization.
